# Conditional display for total in matrix

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

I have a matrix with the following fields:

I add a total for level2

[image]
How can I hide level2 when it's blank and I need to keep the total for level1?

For example the following picture, For the line "Moto" I need to hide the line when  level 2 is null  I need to keep to display the total?

Expected results:

[image]

I put an example here
https://drive.google.com/file/d/10s7o4Ojl4JAq7qIjIAY29hB99tRGLyIZ/view?usp=drivesdk

Comment: Don't have enough information here to reproduce but I'm assuming something like CALCULATE( [number of leads] , filter( Table, NOT( ISBLANK( [number of leads] )) )

Though you might have to convert your measure to a column for this to work correctly.

Comment: I am a newbie with powerbi. Why I need to convert the measure to a column? I didn't get the idea.

Comment: @gscott I update my question with pbix file.

Comment: First note - if at all possible, transform your "null" text values to blanks in power query as a start. It'll handle your categorical variables fundamentally different as blanks versus as text values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put in logic to deal with those using `ISBLANK` and `ISFILTERED`.

```
Measure =
IF (
    ISBLANK ( SELECTEDVALUE ( Table1[Dim6] ) ) && ISFILTERED ( Table1[Dim6] ),
    BLANK (),
    SUM ( Table1[AN] )
)
```

The result looks like this:

[image: Matrix Visual]

---

The [ISFILTERED function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/isfiltered-function-dax) is critical here since it's false at the subtotal level but true at the leaf level.

Answer (score 1):

Converting to nulls is my take on your issue here. The categorization of these variables as text "null" values is creating an issue for you:

Here's three options for visuals if you convert these to blanks / NAs:

[image]